# Non-technical terms on Elasticsearch, Logstash and Kibana

Tags: json, csv, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have a doubt. I do know that Logstash allows us to input csv/log files and filter it using separators and columns. And it will output into elasticsearch for it to be used by Kibana. However, after writing the conf file, do I need to specify index pattern by using the command:

```
CURL -XPUT 'http://localhost:5601/test' d
```

Because I do know that when you have a JSON file, you will have to define the mapping etc. Do I need to do this step for csv files and other non json files? Sorry for asking, I need to clear my doubt.

Comment: Your question is a little unclear.  Are you asking if you need to manuallly  create a mapping, or ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you insert documents into a new elasticsearch index, a mapping is created for you.  This may not be a good thing, as it's based on the initial value of each field.  Imagine a field that normally contains a string, but the initial document contains an integer - now your mapping is wrong.  This is a good case for creating a mapping.

If you insert documents through logstash into an index named logstash-YYYY-MM-DD (the default), logstash will apply its own mapping.  It will use any pattern hints you gave it in grok{}, e.g.:

```
%{NUMBER:bytes:int}
```

and it will also make a "raw" (not analyzed) version of each string, which you can access as myField.raw.  This may also not be what you want, but you can make your own mapping and provide it as an argument in the elasticsearch{} output stanza.

You can also make templates, which elasticsearch will apply when an index pattern matches the template definition.

So, you only need to create a mapping if you don't like the default behaviors of elasticsearch or logstash.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you! I finally understand what does it mean by raw :)